# IIS Server sending response code 500 while trying to login

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I developed an ASP.NET MVC Core application using Visual Studio 2019.
The application is running fine when I run it in Visual Studio.

When I host the same application in IIS Server, the 1st page is loading fine, but when I try to login, IIS Server is sending response code 500 internal server error. I tried after installing `dotnet-hosting-3.1.22-win.exe`, but the problem did not get resolved.

While running application using Visual Studio, I see the below status code (302)-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HtTy.png)

While running the same application after hosting on IIS Server I see this status code (500 Internal Server error):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOtQM.png)

Please I am unable solve this problem please help me and resolve my issues

Comment: The actual 500 error page is the key to learn the cause. Either you analyze that in your browser's developer tools, or you use FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Are you able to visit the other pages of your application that do not need to log in? Are you seeing the sub status code along with the status code on the browser screen? Make sure you have installed the correct version of the Hosting bundle and .NetCore runtime. It could be possible that something is wrong with your Login module. You could try to configure Failed Request Tracing rule as already suggested by Lex Li.